# Need to copy/transfer files from Amazon S3 Storage to FTP Server

Tags: azure, amazon-s3, ftp, azure-virtual-machine, ftp-server

I need to copy/transfer files from AWS S3 storage to my FTP Server. I have read many blogs but FTP as a destination is not supported.
Is there any way to transfer files directly to FTP Server (do not need any file system in between).
Can I use python to achieve this functionality? I tried doing this using WinSCP but using WinSCP first I need to download the S3 file to my file system and then upload it to the FTP Server.
Do we have any Azure service using which we can achieve this? ADF does not support FTP as a sink as of yet.

Comment: Depends, on that "directly" means. If you mean that you do want the data flow directly between S3 and FTP, you would have to use some Amazon feature for that (if they have it) - that's probably not a programming question, hence off-topic here. Or at least use Amazon VM to download from S3 and upload to FTP. Doing it externally will always require as least bandwidth (if you stream the data) or even an intermediate storage (a file system or a memory).

Comment: Want the data to flow directly between S3 to STP Server (no intermediate step/storage). Is there any option to download the S3 file from FTP server?

Comment: FTP server cannot do anything proactively. It only responds to requests from an FTP client. Of course unless you have a different access to that server, other than FTP.

Comment: I think, maybe you need to rephrase your question and try to get a clear understanding of the components you are dealing with. S3 is a storage service, you can mount it to a server and get you file off it.

Comment: Maybe you can try another way, not copy files directly to your FTP server. I suggest copying to the Azure Storage, and then mount the Azure storage to your FTP server. Then the ADF is useful.

Comment: Any more updates? Could the way solve your problem?

Comment: None. Just treated the FTP server as a file system and copied the files there. Thanks for your inputs.

Comment: Will you do further searching or just keep the current state?

Comment: Going forward with the current state as of now.